# ngx-bootstrap dropdown not working with SPA Visual Studio Community 2017

Tags: angular, angular2-components, ngx-bootstrap

I am trying to integrate ngx-bootstraps dropdown into my SPA template with Visual Studio. I have the following;

package.json;

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/http": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "4.2.5",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
    "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "angular2-carousel": "1.0.12",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "2.0.0-rc.0",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "3.10.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.21.0",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  }
```

I have added following to my webpack.config.vendor.js;

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const treeShakableModules = [
    '@angular/animations',
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/forms',
    '@angular/http',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    'zone.js',
];
const nonTreeShakableModules = [
    'bootstrap',
    'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
    'es6-promise',
    'es6-shim',
    'event-source-polyfill',
    'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
    'angular2-carousel',
    'hammerjs',
    'ngx-bootstrap',
    'jquery',
];
```

I have run the webpack command (I have no error when running my app).

My app.browser.module.ts is;

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppModuleShared } from './app.shared.module';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { CarouselModule } from "angular2-carousel";
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        AppModuleShared,
        CarouselModule,
        BsDropdownModule.forRoot()
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: 'BASE_URL', useFactory: getBaseUrl }
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}

export function getBaseUrl() {
    return document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].href;
}
```

To note I have also tried;

```
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
```

In my nav.component.ts I have;

```
import { Injectable, Inject, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { APP_CONFIG, AppConfig } from '../../../app.config';

@Component({
    selector: 'nav-menu',
    templateUrl: './navmenu.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./navmenu.component.css']
})
export class NavMenuComponent {
    constructor(@Inject(APP_CONFIG) private config: AppConfig) { }
}
```

and html is;

```
 <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']" dropdown>
                    <a [routerLink]="['/services']" dropdownToggle>
                        Our services
                    </a>
                    <ul  *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider dropdown-divider"></li>
                        <li role="menuitem">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
```

There code is throwing no errors in the console but the drop down is not appearing? When I inspect the code on the Services Link in chrome I get the following html;

```
<li _ngcontent-c1="" dropdown="" ng-reflect-router-link-active="link-active">
     <a _ngcontent-c1="" dropdowntoggle="" ng-reflect-router-link="/services" href="/services">
         Our services
     </a>
     <!---->
</li>
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong please?

Comment: I noticed that you have `routerLink` and `dropdownToggle` on the same tag, this may be a reason. Also this doesn't make much sense because you'll be redirected to another page before dropdown is rendered.

Comment: Ok, I see where you are coming from, I tried removing this and the dropdown still doesnt appear though? Anything else I can check for you?

Comment: You can create a reproduction on plunkr/stackblitz or provide a repo, then I'll take a look at it. starter templates:

Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/0NipkZrnckZZROAcnjzB?p=preview

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts